# Distinguishing SSE datatypes under visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vectorization, sse

Under gcc I would write:

```
typedef __v16qi       vUInt8;
```

or even:

```
typedef unsigned char vUInt8 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16)));
```

This makes it possible to distinguish between e.g. a vector of 16 x uint8 and a vector of 4 x uint32. It also makes possible function overloading, e.g.

```
vUInt8 vAdd(vUInt8 a, vUInt8 b) { return _mm_add_epi8(a, b); }
vUInt16 vAdd(vUInt16 a, vUInt16 b)  { return _mm_add_epi16(a, b); }
```

or even just:

```
template<class T> T vAdd(T a, T b)  { return a + b; }
```

I have ended up with quite a lot of cross-platform code where the SIMD details are encapsulated like this(*), and along with alternative implementations for Neon and Altivec it makes for very convenient cross-platform compilation under gcc.

The problem is that this just doesn't seem to be an option under MS Visual C. I am not that familiar with Windows but, as far as I can see, MSVS only understands the generic _m128i type, which makes it impossible to distinguish between different element sizes. As far as I can see, this completely scuppers my setup where I encapsulate all the vector code in cross-platform functions such as vAdd().

If I try:

```
typedef __m128i vUInt8;
typedef __m128i vUInt16;
```

then that doesn't help me because vUInt8 and vUInt16 are treated as completely synonymous and interchangeable by the compiler, so I still cannot overload vAdd for different element sizes.

Can anyone suggest a solution that would enable me to write code of the sort I am describing here, but that would compile under Visual C? I am hoping to find a way to do that rather than e.g. having to set up mingw, since this is for a C extension for python (and my understanding is that I can only really assume that MSVC is available, not anything gcc-like).

(*) clearly this isn't practical for all vector instructions, but it works well for me with the relatively straightforward arithmetic operations I am doing.

Comment: Write class types which wrap the underlying vectorized data, give such class types members (or define free functions operating on such class types) which call the appropriate intrinsic. i.e. `struct vUInt8 { __m128i value; }; struct vUInt16 { __m128i value; };`

Comment: @user2407038: Or use a C++ library that already does that, such as Agner Fog's VCL, with transparent constructors and value operators back to `__m128i`.  https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=1013.  It even has operator overloads for stuff like `+` and `-` to let you do `v1 += v2` instead of `v1 = _mm_add_epi8(v1, v2)`.  Or there are some SIMD wrapper libraries that are more portable between SSE/AVX and NEON.  I don't think VCL is.

Comment: Thank you both. I couldn't quite picture how to make the struct/class approach work transparently, but from Agner Fog's library I have been reminded about how to use the typecast operator to overcome that obstacle. I'll either just use his library, or write a lightweight equivalent that follows user2407038's approach along with the typecast operator etc.